# How can I disable threading in Flask?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, gunicorn

I have the following bit of code:

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
db = sqlite3.connect('/etc/db.sqlite')

@app.route('/')
def handle():
    # run a query and return a response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 8080, debug=True)
```

However, when I try to perform some operations on the database object in the request handler, I get the following exception from sqlite3 because it is not a thread-safe library and the query is run from a different thread that Flask spawns, and not from the main thread:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 139886422697792 and this is thread id 139886332843776
```

I am aware that the "proper" way to do this is to have a function to create an instance of the `sqlite3.Connection` object and store it in the Flask `g` global, as outlined here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/sqlite3/. However, when running this application on production, I use `gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 app:app`, and there it works fine, because the threads are spawned at the beginning in this case.

While the Flask `g` global method works in all cases, I would really like to avoid the overhead of creating and destroying `sqlite3.Connection` objects with every request. So, I would like to disable threading in Flask so that the above code can run without causing issues.

However, even when I change the last line of the above code to `app.run(..., threaded=False)`, I am unable to avoid this error. It seems that Flask still spawns a thread for handling requests.

So, how can I disable threading with Flask?

Comment: Not a solution, just a note. It wasnt mentioned, but threaded=false is the default for flask. The threading that's happening is caused by gunicorn. Even with threading set to "false" on flask, you'll still have n threads (as far as SQLlite is concerned) where n is your number of gunicorn workers.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `sqlite3` module directly in flask. Use `Flask_sqlalchemy`
I had lots of trouble trying to set up databases on sqlite without it. As soon as I made the switch it was sooooo much easier. You can connect to multiple types of SQL databases too!

Flask sqlalchemy:

http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/

Really the best guide for flask out there:

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database

Answer (score 1):

Use scoped_session to avoid this:

```
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))()
```

Comment: Why will this work? Which libraries are you importing these names from?

Comment: they're all from SQLAlchemy: from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

Comment: Does this disable threading in flask?

Comment: no, that actually makes threading works in both ends